# Flash errors 2007, 2025; increasing score seems to crash game

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I'm working on a small game in Flash to get the basics of AS3 down. However, I ran into some problem that I can't seem to figure out.

I have my Player 'avatar', which is supposed to pick up small coins that appear from the right side of the screen. These coins move to the left where my player character can pick them up. I want to remove them from the screen and increase the score by 10 when the character picks up a coin.

However, there seems to be a couple of bugs: when I pick up a coin, I get these errors:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
```

I push the coins to an array and then run a foreach loop on them to make them move and call hitTestObject() on them:

```
for each(var muntje:Muntje in geldArray)
        {
            muntje.moveMuntje();
            if(playerLola.hitTestObject(muntje))
            {
                removeChild(muntje);
                gameScore.addToValue(10);
            }
        }
```

Also, when I pick up a coin, the game doesn't entirely crash; it just seems to stop a bit, throw (spam) a couple of those error messages and then it increases the score by 10, after which the game continues.

EDIT: I guess I can't use removeChild() here because 'muntje' isn't actually a child? I tried things like `stage.removeChild(muntje)`, but that just wouldn't work either. How would I go about removing the coins from the stage?

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most safe way to remove DisplayObject is

```
if (muntje && muntje.parent) muntje.parent.removeChild(muntje);
```

This way you don't care who holds the object, it just gets removed from anything (if it was added to anything at all.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did it. However, my score updates with more than 10 because uh, hitTestObject seems to trigger addToValue() more than once. Is there a way to make it trigger just once? Perhaps with a boolean value?

Comment: After the coin is collected, you might remove in from geldArray at all, so it don't trigger again.

Comment: How would I do that? With splice? I'm pretty new to AS3 so I don't know most of these techniques. I'll go read up on this :) Thanks for your time!

Comment: Run the `for` cycle backwards: `for (var i:int = geldArray.length - 1; i>=0; i--)`. Then you can do `geldArray.splice(i, 1)` - this removes one element at pos i. Array is one of the essential classes, gain practice with it! :D

Comment: Will do :) I put the code you provided in, but now my other coins stop moving when I collect one ;D I'll try to figure it out! Thanks again.